# Binary tree search delete a node complexity

Tags: c++, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I try to calculate the complexity of the binary tree search node deletion.I want to calculate complexity in all 3 cases(worst,average complexity and best) more detalied.How to choose the mathematical formula? T(n) = ?

```
    Nod* delete(Nod*& rad, const int& c)
{
    //Nod has:c(information:int),nextSt(left:pointer to Nod),nextDr(right pointer to Nod)
    Nod* aux;
    if (rad == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else
        if (c< rad->c && c != rad->c) {
            rad->nextSt() = delete(rad->nextSt(), c);
            return rad;
        }
        else
            if (c > rad->c) {
                rad->nextDr() = delete(rad->nextDr(), c);
                return rad;
            }
            else
                if (rad->nextSt() != NULL && rad->nextDr() != NULL) {
                    aux = minim(rad->nextDr());
                    rad->setElem(aux->element());
                    rad->nextDr() = delete(rad->nextDr(), rad->c);
                    return rad;
                }
                else {
                    aux = rad;
                    Nod* repl;
                    if (rad->nextSt() == NULL)
                        repl = rad->nextDr();
                    else
                        repl = rad->nextSt();
                    delete rad;
                    return repl;
                }

}
```

Comment: This depends on whether your node is balanced. Node delete is O(depth) in binary trees. O(depth) = O(n) for unbalanced trees (n being node count), while it's just O( log(n) ) for balanced trees. In other words, show us your insertion algorithm :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove operation on the binary search tree always takes O(h) time. Where h is tree height.

So if your tree is good balanced, it's height is log(N). And remove operation will also take O(log(N)) time. It's the best case.

The worst case appears when all your nodes use right/left child as the next node. This case may appear if you insert sorted items (for example 1,2,3,4,5) to the tree. So height of this tree is N and remove operation will take O(N) time. Binary search tree is not better linked list in this case.

So average complexity is between log(N) and N

For more information about binary search tree and complexity theory see Cormen's Introduction to algorithm